# Name That ...Name? 12

Tags: riddle, knowledge

My compound name gives value to a geometric place

An economic box gives me a famous pace

A female author less known but existed pretty well

But many people know me fictitiously, sad to tell

Name the *last* name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the answer to this

> EDGEWORTH?

My compound name gives value to a geometric place

> It gives worth (value) to an edge (geometry).

An economic box gives me a famous pace

> Refers to the [Edgeworth Box](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_box) named after [Francis Ysidro Edgeworth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Ysidro_Edgeworth), an economist.

A female author less known but existed pretty well

> This refers to Francis’ aunt, [Maria Edgeworth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Edgeworth), an author of children’s novels.

But many people know me fictitiously, sad to tell

> The perhaps more famous Edgeworth is [Miles Edgeworth](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miles_Edgeworth), a character from Ace Attorney.

Comment: This is correct